# MySQL Workbech ERROR 1064 Insert problem don't know where is it problem?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

create table sales
(purchase_number int not null auto_increment,
date_of_purchase date not null,
customer_id INT,
company_id varchar (10) not null,
primary key (purchase_number)
);

alter table sales
add foreign key (customer_id) references customers (customer_id) on delete cascade;

create table customers
(customer_id INT,
first_name varchar (255),
last_name varchar (255),
email_address varchar (255),
number_of_complaints INT,
primary key (customer_id)
);

alter table customers
add unique key (email_address);

alter table customers
change column number_of_complaints number_of_complaints int default 0;

Insert into customers (first_name, last_name, number_of_complaints)
values ('Movlan', 'ALiyev', '1');

Comment: Please add the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

2 errors -

1. you cannot create a foreign key on a table which does not exist
   so move alter table sales to just before the insert
2. customer_id
   does not have a default value and is not null so you need to provide
   it in your insert - you may wish to change this column to
   auto_increment..